# passwd and shadow were deleted how do I fix this?

Tags: ubuntu

...and I do NOT have backups in

> var/backups

for some unknown reason. First question, why do I fix this? Second question, why was there no backup in

> var/backups

?

Comment: ???   No password needed to see var/backups.   You do need sudo to access

Comment: Ive voted to close as this may range from "easy" to "not worth the effort" depending on you system - we really beed more details - like OS variant, use case (single or multiuser, server or desktop), and the amount of your time its worth to rexover the system.

Comment: Also, why would you expect to have things in /var/backups - ie did you set up any backup process?

Comment: I think your 1st, 2nd, 3rd, Ad infinitum question, should be _why & how_ were they deleted.